# Adding Library to Android/Eclipse project

Tags: android

Hello there I am trying to add a Library to an Android application.  I was attempting to follow the instructions on this page... [Page that I looked at to add a Library to my project](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#addexternallibrary)

I am attempting to add the ksoap2 jar in a attempt to call a SOAP webservice.

Comment: Add a question. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a "lib" folder in your projectdirectory, paste there your ".jar" file.

After that, refresh your project in eclipse, rightclick your jarfile and choose "Build Path"->"Add to Build Path"

Comment: I think that would work, But you know what I did, I right clicked on the project->Went to build Path->Made sure I was in Java Build Path and the Libraries Tab->Add External Jars->and Searched for the Jar.  that seemed to have done it.  I am going to see if I can't import some of the libraries.